# SVG file messed up in Illustrator CC

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I used an online [LaTeX tool](http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/) to create an .svg file. It looks perfect in IE browser, but is completely messed up in Illustrator CC. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: That works. Open in Inkscape > save in .ps > open in Illustrator. Do you want to enter your response as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open in Inkscape
2. save as .ps
3. open in Illustrator.